# How to rebuild Jenkins job with old stable git revision if the latest revision fails the build

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, gitlab

I am running a Jenkins job that builds automatically when change is pushed to master.

However, I want to re-run the Job if the Latest commit fails the build, with the older revision that is stable.

How can I achieve that in Jenkins.

I could fetch the latest-stable build using Jenkins URL but what next?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the build flow plugin (or pipleline), then this solution would work for you.

Build flow dsl script example as follow

```
def buildInstance
//Ingore the failure here to avoid flow stop
ignore(FAILURE){
    buildInstance = build("normal_git_job")
}

//Something goes wrong, try build another job
if (buildInstance.result.equals(FAILURE)){
    build("special_git_job")
}
```